# Virtual Win XP Mode stopped HP LJ Pro M1212nf MFP printing in Win 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtual-machine, printer, hp-laserjet

Virtual Win XP Mode stopped HP LJ Pro M1212nf MFP printing in Win 7 Pro:  I am running Windows 7 Pro with Virtual Windows XP Mode.  My printer is HP LaserJet Pro M1212nf MFP attached directly to a USB port of the computer.  This printer was working fine in Windows 7, until I tried to attach the printer to the Virtual Windows XP Mode in order to load the printer driver in the Virtual Windows XP Mode.  At that point, the printer disappeared from the list of USB devices on the toolbar at the top of the window of the Virtual Windows XP Mode.  After installing the printer driver in the Virtual Windows XP Mode, the printer did not work in that mode and also no longer worked in Windows 7.  In Windows 7 and in the Virtual Windows XP Mode, print files are sent to the print queue, but are never printed.  In Windows 7, the print queue states that the printer is offline.  In the Virtual Windows XP Mode, the printer can be toggled from "Print Offline" to "Print Online", but no print files are ever printed from the print queue.  The printer acts as though it is no longer connected to the computer, even though it is still physically connected to the USB port of the computer.  How can I get the printer to work again in Windows 7?  (At this point, I am no longer interested in using the Virtual Windows XP Mode.)

I have tried a large number of things to find and fix the printer problem, but have had no success. Device Manager cannot see the printer even though it is physically connected via USB port (have tried different USB ports) to the computer. Restoring Win 7 and Virtual Win XP Mode to times before the problem does not fix the problem. How can I get the computer to see the printer, so that I can print again in Win 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actions that completely solved the printer problem in the question above were to open Devices and Printers, right click on the printer icon, click on Remove Device, restart the computer, open Devices and Printers, and click on Add a device.

Answer (score 0):

Take it out of Virtual Win XP Mode.  You only need to use this for application that can't run properly on Windows 7.  Note; if it ain't broke, don't break it by trying to fix something that doesn't need to be fixed.

Comment: I had wanted to use the Virtual Win XP Mode to run a XP application that cannot run in Win 7 and to print from that application using the HP LJ Pro M1212nf MFP (my only printer) that I had been using to print in Win 7 and that I want to continue to use to print in Win 7.  However, if the Virtual Win XP Mode is going to lead to problems using my printer in Win 7, then I am no longer interested in using the Virtual Win XP Mode.  I have shutdown the Virtual Win XP Mode, but that action did not solve the problem.

Comment: When you wrote "Take it out of Virtual Win XP Mode", did you mean that I should uninstall Virtual Win XP Mode?  I want to get the printer working in Win 7 again.  I have tried a large number of things to find and fix the printer problem, but have had no success.  Device Manager cannot see the printer even though it is physically connected via USB port (have tried different USB ports) to the computer.  Restoring Win 7 and Virtual Win XP Mode to times before the problem does not fix the problem.  How can I get the computer to see the printer, so that I can print again in Win 7?

Comment: Unplug the USB cable from your printer and power it off.  Power the printer on, then plug the USB cable in to the printer and computer. On your computer, go to Start > Devices and Printers.  Go to File > Device Manager.  Go to Action > Scan for Hardware Changes.  If your system doesn't pick up the printer, then it means you should try a different USB port or cable.  Note: if you don't need Virtual Win XP, uninstall it.

Comment: The suggested actions (which I had tried before I posted the question) did not result in any changes when I tried them again and did not solve the problem.  Device Manager lists no category "Printers" in its tree.  Before I posted the question, I spent many hours searching my computer (in Win 7 and in Virtual Win XP Mode), including searching the event logs and looking for any changes in any files (including all hidden files) around the time that the printer problem first appeared, and searching the internet for help, all with no success.

Comment: Nine days before the printer problem, I saw a notice (that said "USB driver update") flash briefly on my computer screen in the lower right corner, and then got a small Microsoft window that said to "Restart computer for the changes to take effect".  There were no options to decline the update or undo the update.  This update surprised me since I have Win 7 Update (and all my software)configured to prompt me first before downloading and installing any updates.  A check of the System Event Log around the time of the update showed 2 events:

Comment: You'd be looking for changes in the USB list.  If your system doesn't detect any changes when Scan for Hardware Changes after unplugging and plugging the USB plug in, it means the USB cable is bad, the USB port is bad on your computer, or your printer isn't communicating to your computer.

Comment: Event 20005 Source User PnP Task (7005) Driver Management has concluded the process to add Service usbccgp for Device Instance ID USB\VID_03f0&PID_052A\000000000QJ1023rp1A with the following status: 0.  Then, Event 20001 Source User PnP Task (7005) Driver Management concluded the process to install driver FileRepository\usb.inf_amd64_neutral_efc1d9d1a972acd0\usb.inf for Device Instance ID USB\VID_03F0&PID_052A\000000000OJ1023RPR1A with the following status: 0x0.  My computer system (including all my PnP devices, including my printer) continued to work well until the current printer problem.

Comment: However, when I tried to restore Win 7 to times before the unauthorized USB driver update, the computer hung for hours at the initializing stage of the restore, until I unplugged the power cord and restarted the computer.  No problems restoring Win 7 and Virtual Win XP Mode to times after the unauthorized USB driver update but before the printer problem.

Comment: With the printer, I tried two USB cables, both of with currently work fine with another USB device (external hard drive).  With the printer, I tried three different USB ports on the computer, all of which ports currently work fine with other USB devices (flash drives, external hard drive).  So, the USB cables and the USB ports on the computer all seem to be fine.  The small LCD display on the printer is unchanged since before the printer problem began and still seems to be working fine now, so no clues there in what is accessible re the printer from the printer itself via its buttons/display

Comment: Your printer or your print service/system registry is hosed.  Confirm your printer works by connecting it to a different computer and seeing if you can add and print from it.  If you can, then it means that update or something that happened to your registry or print service.  Those event descriptions indicate the USB device is functioning, but it's not mapping to the printer service to be able to communicate.  If you spend more than 4 hours troubleshooting, you're better off formatting and starting your entire system from scratch.